# What's the way Wordpress integrates tinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, tinymce

There's an editor tinyMCE written in *JS*. It's said to be a native WP visual editor.

I'd like to remove/add some buttons and extend some functionality to the editor like adding prepared *bootstrap blocks*.

According to the official tinyMCE manual all I have to do is creating a JS file and do all the job there. Here's an example of [a simple plugin](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/creating-a-plugin/)

I created a WP plugin which loads the JS sippet.

```
add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', array( &$this, 'add_tinymce_plugin' ) );

function add_tinymce_plugin( $plugin_array ) {
    $plugin_array['example'] = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/js/index.js';
    return $plugin_array;
}
```

I can see the the plugin was loaded through `tinyMCE.pluginManager` object via js console.

But nothing happens. I mean the code does not work. I tried tons of the simpliest js snippets like

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  toolbar: false
});
```

All of them successfully load  but never affects.
According to [WP codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE) I need not only js files but php too even to add a simpe button. Why should I use PHP to work with JS editor? Can I just use JS?